# PHP/MySQL category div wrapping issue

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm fairly certain I'm overlooking something obvious, but here it goes.

I'm working with two tables in MySQL, one for `categories` and the other for `works`. I've successfully joined the tables together and am referencing both with `mysql_fetch_array`. (I am aware this is deprecated.)

I am also able to successfully display the category name once, followed by all of the works in that category.

I run into an issue, however, with wrapping a div around all of the entries in a category. The reason I want to wrap one div around the entries is I'm using collapsibles to keep the information organized. The category name serves as trigger for the collapsible, and the works are expanded/collapsed when the user clicks the category name.

(I'm also opening each image in a FancyBox, but that's irrelevant to my question.)

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM gallery
    LEFT JOIN gallery_categories ON gallery.category=gallery_categories.category_id
    ORDER BY category ASC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't join tables.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

$category = null;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $image = stripslashes($row['image']);
    $timestamp = stripslashes($row['timestamp']);

    if ($category != $row['category']) {
        $category = $row['category'];

        ?>

        <div class="page_collapsible" id="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>"><h3><div class="title"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></div></h3></div>

        <div class="gallery-grid">

            <div class="item">
                <div class="content"><a class="fancybox" href="images/works/<?php echo $image ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>, <?php echo $timestamp ?>"><img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo $image ?>" class="thumb" /><div class="thumb-border"></div></a></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php

    }

}
```

The `page_collapsible` class contains the collapsible trigger. The `gallery-grid` class is the wrapper for the content to be collapsed. The `item` class contains information about each entry in the `works` table.

The problem I run into is the code only iterates the first row in the `works` table that matches the category. I have tried removing the IF statement for the category display and instead tried `GROUP BY`, but ran into the same problem. If I move the item class and the `</div>` for the gallery-grid class outside of the IF statement, each entry in the `works` table is displayed successfully, but the gallery-grid class wraps each subsequent category and corresponding entries. If I move the item class but leave the `</div>` for the gallery-grid class where it is currently, the collapsible content is blank, and the entries are outside of the collapsible, though properly displayed under their corresponding category.

Ultimately, how do I wrap all of the entries in a given category ONCE, while displaying ALL entries in a given category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, aren't you looking for something like this?
You need to write the start/end of the wrapper only when category changes (preserve `order by category`). The items are written unconditionally in every loop pass.

Note `if($category != null){...}` is because of not closing the first wrapper and the last `</div>` outside the loop is for closing the last wrapper

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
 $image = stripslashes($row['image']);
 $timestamp = stripslashes($row['timestamp']);

 if ($category != $row['category']) {
    if($category != null){
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }
    $category = $row['category'];
    ?>
    <div class="page_collapsible" id="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>"><h3><div class="title"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></div></h3></div>
    <div class="gallery-grid">
    <?php 
 }
 ?>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="content"><a class="fancybox" href="images/works/<?php echo $image ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>, <?php echo $timestamp ?>"><img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo $image ?>" class="thumb" /><div class="thumb-border"></div></a></div>
 </div>
 <?php    
 }
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! A very simple solution, just what I was looking for. I wish I could accept your answer multiple times over. Thank you so much! :)